# Overriding a clock pin with manual control, then clocking again

Tags: origen-sdk

An interesting issue arose with a device whose SWD_CLK pin is shared as a 'device boot mode' pin (ROM/Flash boot, etc.). The specification states that the SWD_CLK should be held high for some time before functioning as SWD_CLK.

The origen_swd plugin drives the clock high to 'enable' it, so the timeset for this pin must be 'return low' in order to clock. But, when I try to drive this high and hold it high, it begins clocking. Is there a way to disable the timeset for some time, then re-enable it when ready?

The workaround is to change the origen_swd to accept an option to either drive high or drive low to enable, then change the timeset in my application to return high.

Using metaprogramming to just grab and edit instance variables of the timeset may also be a solution, but is there a supported API to handle the tasks like the above?

Thanks

Comment: I should mention as well that I'm using [origen_sim.](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_sim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this would be by making two timing options for the given pin, one with the return low and one without.

```
tester.set_timeset "mode_entry", 40

pin(:swd_clk).drive!(1)

# Sometime later once in mode

tester.set_timeset "func_swd", 40
```

If the tester supports (e.g. V93K) you can also define multiple wave forms for a pin within the same timeset, as shown at the end of this guide section - http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/pattern/timing/#Complex_Timing

Then you would just have a single timeset selection and control the wave you want on the pin like this:

```
pin(:swd_clk).drive!(1)    # Would be defined in the timing as always high

pin(:swd_clk).drive!('P')  # Now start the clk pulse
```

Both of these approaches will work in the generated ATE patterns, however at the time of writing I believe that OrigenSim does not yet support the second approach, so you will have to use the multiple timesets.

As an aside, you sound like you are only looking for a solution that works in simulation and not necessarily required to have the two types of waves within the final ATE pattern.

In that case, you could also try poking the testbench's pin driver force data bit, though I haven't tried this:

```
tester.simulator.poke('origen.pins.swd_clk.force_data[1]', 1);
```

If you have success with that, we should think about adding a convenience API to do this kind of thing in simulation:

```
pin(:swd_clk).force!(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! The timesets approach will also work, and is better than unnecessarily hacking at origen_swd. We will be inheriting a testprogram with who knows what setup, so we'll cross the ATE bridge when we get there. For now, I'm 100% Origen sim. The poking would also work, I just try to stay away from poking when possible and using Origen's non-simulator features whenever possible. Though, I'd support a pin.force! shortcut. Thanks!